# How can I make react router direct to my error page when an undefined route is specified?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently if you navigate to an unknown route react-router thinks that that unknown value is an id and throws a react-style error, such as "cant access property "x" Y is undefined". How can I enable my 404 page to load when an unknown route is passed?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={MainSignedOut} exact />
          <Route path="/mainsignedin" component={MainSignedIn} />
          <Route path="/searchpage" component={SearchPage} />
          <Route path="/mypets" component={MyPets} />
          <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
          <Route exact path="/:id" component={PetPage} /> 
          <Route component={err404} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change this:

```
<Route exact path="/:id" component={PetPage} />
```

to this:

```
<Route exact path="/pets/:id" component={PetPage} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the route /:id, and in the component PetPage when you fetch data from the backend, you should verify if the pet exist or not then you can display error message "pet x is not exist."